# CSS - DIV spacing and hover issues

Tags: css

I have a set of DIVs like so:

```
<div class = 'tag'><a href='#'>gifts for him</a></div>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.tag a,
.tag {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #dcedf8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tag a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #a5c5da;
  color: #fff;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

Basically I want them to look like the following (**gifts for him** as an example hover):

[image]

However mine look like this:

[image]

There is no gap and the hover ignores the padding (I'd like the hover to colour right up to the edges if possible).

If I add `margin: 2px` I get this, which is even worse:

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have make for you a fiddle.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qhzeh27w/)

your css is wrong:

it should look like this:

```
.tag {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  background-color: #dcedf8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right:5px;

}
.tag a{
     color: #666;
          text-decoration: none;
}

.tag:hover {
  background-color: #a5c5da;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.tag:hover a{
    color:#FFF;
      text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks! I see what I did wrong now, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, you need to give the `.tag` alone a margin, not `.tag a`. Try adding this line:

```
.tag { margin: 2px; }
```

Also, give your `.tag a` a height and width of 100% - this will fill in the entire container:

```
.tag a { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

In your current CSS, you're giving both the div containing the anchor tag **as well as** the anchor tag styling, but you only need to be giving it to the `.tag` div in order to space out the containers.

Comment: Aha! You're right, that worked perfectly thanks.  Now is there any way to get the hover to extend to the edges? It stops at the padding, if that makes sense

Comment: Try giving the anchor tag the same padding, so if the container has `padding-left: 6px;` and `padding-right: 6px;`, add it to the `.tag a {}` style above

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.tag a,
.tag {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #666;
  margin:2px;
  background-color: #dcedf8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.tag a:hover {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #a5c5da;
  color: #fff;
  height: 37px;
  line-height: 37px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'tag'><a href='#'>gifts for him</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this used only single

`<a href='#' class="hoverEffect">gifts for him</a>`

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/hkkLz0re/